# Migrating link fields to Drupal 8

Tags: entities, migrations, navigation

I am trying to migrate a link field field_url from a Drupal 7 site to my Drupal 8 one. The link field is compound, it has a title and a url value. In my process plugin I am selecting the right values (field_url_title and field_url_url), but I don't know how to map them in my yaml definition file. What I have:

```
          field_url: field_url_url
          field_url_title: field_url_title
```

...maps correctly the url, but does not populate the title one. What's the destination field machine name I would need to use to add in the link title?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example:

```
field_url:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_url
  process:
    uri: url
    title: title
    options: attributes
```

Because in D8 the `field_url_url` database field changed to `field_url_uri` and the `attributes` to `options`, you can not use direct mapping on this field.

Answer (score 5):

As of Drupal 8.4, the iterator process plugin is deprecated. Use sub_process instead

See change record:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2880427

```
field_url:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_url
  process:
    uri: url
    title: title
    options: attributes
```

Answer (score 4):

As of at least 8.4, the "field_link" plugin should do the trick.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21link%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21FieldLink.php/class/FieldLink/8.4.x

```
process:
  field_new_link_field:
    plugin: field_link
    uri_scheme: 'https://'
    source: field_source_link_field
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to migrate a link and title from source fields to link fields this should work.

```
  'field_web_link/uri': link
  'field_web_link/title': title
```