# How can I migrate URL fields to link fields?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have run migration using ***drush migrate-upgrade*** by setting up Drupal 7 used module in Drupal 8 site and DB path etc. But one  of my content type use field https://www.drupal.org/project/url but now link field is in Drupa 8 and version of this module is not available in Drupal 8.

In support I have gone thorugh https://www.drupal.org/project/url/issues/1778224 but didn't helped much.

How I can transfer data along with revisions data related to this field and create/migrate similar field in Drupal 8 content type (rest of fields got migrated in 8 from 7)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating link fields to Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181697/migrating-link-fields-to-drupal-8)

Comment: yes it seems smilier but I need help for related explanation ie: is that possible to migrate without custom solution. Or there is need to create some custom solution to migrate such data, if so any tutorial links or explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to create solution based on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/writing-migrations-for-contributed-and-custom-modules#field-migrations

[image]

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_url_migrate\plugin\migrate\field;

use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationInterface;
use Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\field\FieldPluginBase;

/**
 * @MigrateField(
 * id = "url",
 * core = {7},
 * type_map = {
 * "url" = "link"
 * },
 * source_module = "url",
 * destination_module = "link"
 * )
 */
class url extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFieldWidgetMap() {
    return [
      'url' => 'link',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFieldFormatterMap() {
    return [
     //'default' => 'link',
      //'url' => 'link',
      'url_external' => 'link',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processFieldValues(MigrationInterface $migration, $field_name, $data) {
    $process = [
      'plugin' => 'sub_process',
      'source' => $field_name,
      'process' => [
        'uri' => 'value',
      ],
    ];
    $migration->setProcessOfProperty($field_name, $process);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also now a contrib module for the URL to Link migration: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_url2link